# Editpost function not working. Problem with "if request.method=='POST':"

Tags: django

The problems seems to be at the line "if request.method=='POST':". Any help is appreciated.

traceback

```
[30/Jan/2019 23:44:22] "GET /testimonypost/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8031
Not Found: /testimonypost/.jpg
[30/Jan/2019 23:44:22] "GET /testimonypost/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 17479

boo
5
boo
a

[30/Jan/2019 23:44:25] "GET /37/testimony/edit HTTP/1.1" 200 5320
Not Found: /37/testimony/.jpg
[30/Jan/2019 23:44:25] "GET /37/testimony/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 17476
[30/Jan/2019 23:44:28] "POST /37/testimony/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4261
Not Found: /37/testimony/.jpg
[30/Jan/2019 23:44:28] "GET /37/testimony/.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 17476
```

template

```
{%extends 'base_form.html'%}
{%block content%}

<form class="form-group" action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{%csrf_token%}
{%for field in form %}



    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <span class="text-danger small">{{field.errors}}</span>
    </div>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2"{{field.label_tag}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{field}}</div>



{%endfor%}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
{%endblock content%}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def TestimonyEdit(request, id=None):
    instance=get_object_or_404(Testimony, id=id)
    print(request.user)
    print('5')
    print(instance.user)
    if instance.user == request.user:
        form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
        print('a')
        return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {"form": form})
        if request.method=='POST':
            form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
            if form.is_valid():
                print('3')
                instance=form.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()
                print('2')
                context={
                    "testimony":testimony
                }

                return render(request, 'testimony_post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('You are unauthorized to edit this post')
```

Comment: Your code not reached to `request.method=='POST'`. YOur code return here `return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {"form": form})`

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking a question. But yes. The template renders.

Comment: Try to remove this line `return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {"form": form})` you saw your code reach to `if request.method=='POST':`

Comment: Doing that gets me this. ValueError: The view Testimony.views.TestimonyEdit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: I add my explaination as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. if instance.user == request.user:
2.    form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
3.     print('a')
4.     return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {"form": form})
5.     if request.method=='POST':
6.         form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
```

Look at this code block.
In **Line 1** it check `instance.user == request.user` if **True** then go to **Line 2**
Then in **Line 3** its print `a` in console/terminal.
Then its go to **Line 4** and return template.
So it can't go to **Line 5** anyhow.

So If you want to reach line 5 then you need to remove line 4 and then if any error found to resolve this.

Update:

```
print('a')
# here you remove previous line
if request.method=='POST':
        form = TestimonyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('3')
            instance=form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            print('2')
            context={
                "testimony":testimony
            }

            return render(request, 'testimony_post.html', context)
return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: Just an added part to my question. How would you render the form page without that line then?

Comment: Thanks! I think I understood your explanation.